# How to show/hide div contents on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In **write_comment** class we have input field **textarea** and **buttons** class, what I want is, **buttons** class content should be displayed on focusing on **textarea**

```
  <div class="write_comment">
      <div class="md-form">
        <textarea type="text" id="form_task_comment" class="form-control" style=""
          name="form_task_comment" value="" placeholder=""></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <span>
          <a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          <a><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Without refactoring your HTML, you will need to use JavaScript to achieve this (you can bind a focus/blur event listener to the textarea).

Comment: I want JavaScript code

Comment: I have tried, but not getting proper output

Comment: Show us the code you've tried and we can help :)

Comment: "I want JavaScript code" - this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply capture the focus event of `textarea` and `show` the required elements

```
$("#form_task_comment").focus(function() {
  $(".buttons").show(); //show when user moves focus in the textarea
});

$("#form_task_comment").on("change, blur", function() {
  $(".buttons").hide(); //hide when user moves focus out of the textarea
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#form_task_comment").focus(function() {
  $(".buttons").show();
});

$("#form_task_comment").on("change, blur", function() {
  $(".buttons").hide();
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="write_comment">
  <div class="md-form">
    <textarea type="text" id="form_task_comment" class="form-control" style="" name="form_task_comment" value="" placeholder=""></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span>
          <a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">123 inside buttons</i></a>
          <a><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">1232 inside buttons</i></a>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```css
.buttons {
  display: none;
}

textarea:focus ~ .buttons { /* can also use + in this case because it's the first element after it */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="write_comment">
  <!-- <div class="md-form"> -->
    <textarea type="text" id="form_task_comment" class="form-control" style=""
    name="form_task_comment" value="" placeholder=""></textarea>
  <!-- </div> -->
  <div class="buttons">
    <span>
      <a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">Button 1</i></a>
      <a><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Button 2</i></a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or like this:

```css
.buttons {
  display: none;
}

textarea:focus ~ .buttons { /* can also use + in this case because it's the first element after it */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="write_comment">
  <div class="md-form">
    <textarea type="text" id="form_task_comment" class="form-control" style=""
    name="form_task_comment" value="" placeholder=""></textarea>
    <div class="buttons">
      <span>
        <a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">Button 1</i></a>
        <a><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Button 2</i></a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$("#form_task_comment").focus(function() {
    $(".button").fadeIn();
});
$("#form_task_comment").focusout(function() {
    $(".button").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: No probs, but the other answer, given by @VXp is also truly remarkable.